# How can I call Xamarin Build app from Cmd?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I Created a Xamarin Form App. its OK and works perfectly.

Now I Want pragmatically Modify one of resource (img) of source app and then build it pragmatically for many customer separately.

**How can I call Xamarin Build app from Cmd?**

**How can I Call Xamarin Build for iOS with different AppleId for Each Customer?**